# Cannot use O2 rewards on Play Store; got error code OR-RCP-01

Tags: google-play-store

Tried to use O2 rewards to buy something on Play Store but I can't as I need to enable it (add O2 billing?). But every time I try to put it on, I get the error code [OR-RCP-01].

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I tried googling about using O2 rewards on Play Store, but I didn't get any convincing results. Just to confirm, are you sure it's possible to use it directly on Play Store, instead of redeeming it from another app like [Priority: Gig Tickets & Perks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goldengekko.o2pm)?